# Double url by login wp-admin Wordpress(localhost to server)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with login in on my website server with Wordpress.
I have converted my localhost website to the server and I want to login but the url I see is: 
www.domain.nl/domain.nl//wp-admin/

and of course i wanted to see:

www.domain.nl/wp-admin

This is the error is see:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/domain.nl/public_html/domain.nl/wp-content/themes/name/functions.php:32)
>   in /home/domain.nl/public_html/domain.nl/wp-includes/pluggable.php on
>   line 1179

If i go to www.domain.nl I see the website but the only problem is I can't login.

FUNCTION.PHP CODE:

```
<?php

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

function b2w_theme_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'ie10_css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'navbar_css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/navbar-static-top.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'carousel_css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/carousel.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style_css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css' );

}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b2w_theme_styles');

function b2w_theme_js() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b2w_theme_js')


?>

<?php

function theme_option_setup() {
    add_theme_support('menus');
    register_nav_menu('primary', 'Primary Header Menu Navigation');
}

add_action('init', 'theme_option_setup');
?>

<?php

    require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'NAME' ),
    ) );

?>
```

Comment: A few possible causes.. First, view the WP database with PHPMyadmin and review the wp_options table, particularly the value for siteurl   
Check the wp-admin folder via FTP for a .htaccess file that might have bad rewrite rules in it.

Comment: The value for siteurl is: http://(www.domain.nl)/ and the wp-admin folder doesn't have a .htacces file

Comment: @DuaneLortie the problem is within the functions.php. Here is the code: